# How Not Delete message from MQ by throwing Exception using Spring-JMS

Tags: java, spring, jms

I am using the spring-jms messageListenerContainer to listen to messages. When something wrong happens, I want to throw an exception and stop deleting the message from MQ. I want to use only AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE Session for MQ. How can I achieve this? What kind of Exception should be thrown so that message will not be removed from the MQ and resent again?

Answer (score 0):

We have similar requirements in our project. Although we use IBM WMQ but this will give you some idea of how this can be achieved.

1. Read the message from MQ say #Queue1. By read I mean extract (read & delete) and not just browse the message.
2. While Processing the message if any error occurs then push the message to some other queue say #Queue2.
3. Create a router which brings all the messages from #Queue2 to #Queue1. Alternatively, you can check and process #Queue2 before processing the messages on #Queue1.

This is how we replay the same message again and again in case of an error or exception.

Answer (score 0):

With `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE` mode, messages are automatically removed from a queue after they are delivered to an application.

Using intermediate queues as suggested by @user2004685 requires additional plumbing. I would suggest using a transacted session. Receive message under a transaction and if there is any error while processing the message, call `rollback()` so that the message is available for redelivery.